# symfony2 custom validator FatalErrorException

Tags: validation, symfony

I am using Symfony2 and I am trying to build a custom validator for my class.

I followed the guide found [Here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html)

I am receiving a weird error:

`FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Cannot redeclare class Acme\MyProject\Validator\Constraints\isUniqueNameInPlaces in /home/myfolder/src/Acme/MyProjectBundle/Validator/Constraints/isUniqueNameInPlaces.php line 123`

However, file isUniqueNameInPlaces.php is only 14 lines long.
I am sure I did something stupid, but I can not find out what. Can someone give me a hand?

Here is my isUniqueNameInPlaces

```
  <?php

  // src/Acme/MyProject/Validator/Constraints/UniqueNameInPlaces.php
  namespace Acme\MyProject\Validator\Constraints;

  use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

  /**
  * @Annotation
  */
  class isUniqueNameInPlaces extends Constraint
  {
      public $message = 'Name is not unique';
  }
```

And here is its validator

```
  <?php

  // src/Acme/MyProject/Validator/Constraints/isUniqueNameInPlacesValidator.php
  namespace Acme\MyProject\Validator\Constraints;

  use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
  use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

  class isUniqueNameInPlacesValidator extends ConstraintValidator
  {

      public function getTargets()
      {
          return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
      }

      public function validate($protocol, Constraint $constraint)
      {
  //      my logic
      }
  }
```

Comment: are you sure the name of the 2 files reflects the class names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a **isUniqueNameInPlaces** class elsewhere ? Thus the error **Cannot redeclare class**.
Give your isUniqueNameInPlaces class some other name and see if it's ok then.

Edit :

Also Shouldn't your file be
Acme/**MyProject**/Validator/Constraints/isUniqueNameInPlaces.php
rather than
Acme/**MyProjectBundle**/Validator/Constraints/isUniqueNameInPlaces.php ?

Comment: comment your class, empty your cache and try again. What happens ?

Comment: If its not better then blast you cache the hard way :    rm -rf app/cache/*     and try again...

Comment: Commented constraint class and I get: `RuntimeException: The autoloader expected class "Acme\MyProjectBundle\Validator\Constraints\isUniqueNameInPlaces" to be defined in file "/home/myfolder/src/Acme/MyProjectBundle/Validator/Constraints/isUniqueNameInPlaces.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.`

Comment: Shouldn't your file be Acme/MyProject/Validator/Constraints/isUniqueNameInPlaces.php rather than Acme/MyProjectBundle/Validator/Constraints/isUniqueNameInPlaces.php ?   See **MyProject instead of MyProjectBundle** ?

Comment: Yes... you are right! I knew it was a stupid mistake... Thank you very much!